# Price difference digital option : constant vol vs local vol

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-calculus, local-volatility

I got the following **interview** question:

Consider a digital option, it will be priced by using two approaches: 1)constant volatility; 2)local volatility. At the strike, both volatilities are equal. (See the image).

The question is: How to compute the price difference between both approaches?
It is a pencil and paper question, should be solved algebraically.

[image]

Comment: My guess is this involves replication arguments

Comment: looks like homework. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: It is an interview question

Comment: Write the digital as the derivative wrt strike of the vanilla, both in constant vol case and smiled vol case. use the chain rule in the second case. price difference will be vega * skew.